# Given a list of floats, how to differentiate between exact and inexact values?

Tags: python, numbers

```
list=[1.5,1.1,0.5,0.1]
```

given this list, how to find out floats with exact and inexact values in python 3?
i tried to use decimal.

```
Decimal(num)==float(num)
```

but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

**Note:-`list`  is a function. So you can assign it values. But, it is not recommended to do so, because the next time you want to use the function list, it wouldn't be a function anymore**
Your list:-

```
list=[1.5,1.1,0.5,1]

f_val=[]
o_val=[]
for x in list:
    if type(x)==float:
        f_val.append(x)
    else:
        o_val.append(x)
```

Now if you `print(f_val)` You will get a list of exact float values and if you `print(o_val)` you will get a list of inexact float values

Comment: `list` is not a keyword, it is a function. So you can assign it values. But, it is not recommended to do so, because the next time you want to use the function `list`, it wouldn't be a function anymore.

Comment: 2 one-liners:
`floats = list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, float), values))`
`floats = [x for x in values if isinstance(x, float)]`

Comment: @ Anurag Dabas. So you are considering numbers which are of a float type to be exact and int to be inexact? could you please explain?

Comment: Yes I am considering numbers which are of a float type to be exact and any other type i.e int and str to be inexact @Sherif Elnagdy